# InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' but console gives Observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm pretty new to firebase and rxjs but this still doesn't get in my head:

I make a simple query to my firestore database via a Service

**chat.service.ts:**

```
chatsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Chat>;
  chats: Observable<Chat[]>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {
  }

  getChats(): Observable<Chat[]> {
    this.chatsCollection = this.db.collection('chats');
    return this.chatsCollection.valueChanges();
  }
```

**chat.component.ts:**

```
  chats: Observable<Chat[]>;
  constructor(private router: Router, public chatService: ChatService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.chats = this.chatService.getChats();
    console.log(this.chats);
  }
```

**chat.component.html:**

```
<mat-card class="example-card">
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>Your Chats</mat-card-title>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>
    <mat-selection-list #chats>
      <h3 mat-subheader>Chats</h3>
      <mat-list-option *ngFor="let chat of (chats | async)" (click)="handleClick(chats)" [value]="chat.id">
        <img matListAvatar src="./assets/avatar.svg" alt="Avatar Icon">
        <h3 mat-line>{{chat.name}}</h3>
        <p mat-line>test</p>
      </mat-list-option>
    </mat-selection-list>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Now the problem is the async pipe throws an error for getting an object instead of an observable, but I log it before and it says it's an observable? Also if I subscribe to it (for test) it returns my values I want.

[image: data]

[image: Console Output]

Thanks for help in advance!

**Versions used:**

rxjs: 6.3.3
Angular7
firebase: 5.5.6

Comment: would you mind adding some more information about your local environment? eg angular, rxjs, etc versions

Comment: Try using in parenthesis like `let chat of ( chats | async )` else try restarting your app again

Comment: @Suryan didn't work both

Comment: your code is correct, the only way this cannot work is because it's not complaining about that specific `async` pipe. Can you post the entire `chat.component.html`, especially line 8 :)

Comment: @PierreDuc Line 8 was the line with the *ngFor line, either way I pasted all of the code now.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Added Version Informations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `#chats` on the mat-selection-list. It's overwriting your components `chats` variable inside the template. Rename that one to something else, and you are good to go.

```
<mat-selection-list #chatList>
```

Comment: @filip took me a while as well :D

Comment: Wow...Good eyes